# Separate Submit Buttons For Forms Displayed With Jquery UI Tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

Building a Rails 3.1 app Ruby 1.9 with Devise for user authentication.

Since i'm using Devise to authenticate users I used jquery UI tabs display in the users/edit view. I have one tab to display form for user profile settings and and another for user security settings.

Problem is when i click submit to update either profile or security information  it attempts to submit the forms for both. I have the submit buttons set up for each tab separately. How can i set this up so that i can submit the forms on each tab individually?

My users/edit.html.erb file

```
div id="tabs">
<ul id="user-config-tabs">
<li><a href="#profile-tab">Profile Settings</a></li>
<li><a href="#security-tab">Security Settings</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="profile-tab"> <!-- Start security settings tab info-->
<%= render 'profilesettings'%>
</div>
<div id="security-tab"> <!-- Start Profile settings tab info-->
<%= render 'securitysettings'%>
</div>
</div>
```

Profile settings PArtial

```
<h3 style = "text-align: left">Profile Settings</h3>
<div class="row">
<p id="privacy"><%=link_to "privacy policy", privacy_path%></p>
<div class="span6 offset3">
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
```

```
<fieldset>
<legend>General Information</legend>
 <div><%= f.label "First Name" %>
 <%= f.text_field :name, :autofocus => true %>
 <%= f.label "Last Name" %>
 <%= f.text_field :last_name, :autofocus => true %>
  <%= f.label "Age" %>
 <%= f.text_field :age, :autofocus => true%>
 <%= f.label "Gender" %>
 <%= f.select :gender, User::GENDER_TYPES, prompt: 'Select'%>
 </div>
 </fieldset>
  <div><%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %></div>
 <% end %>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just let the whole form submit but then only use the information that you want to ?

If you dont want the page to submit then I would use ajax to submit the form and serialize only what you need. For example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/post_path",
  type: 'POST',
  cache: false,  
  async: false,
  data: $("#security_form").serialize(),
    success: function(data){
      if(data.valid == "true"){
        $('#notice').html("Updated succesfully").slideDown();
      }else{
        $('#errors').html(data.errors).slideDown();
      }
    }
});
```

Then you can handle this in the controller.